# Filtering data for multiple years by date range given by months and days in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a data frame, df, in the following format for multiple years (6hourly).

I need to filter the dates, for every year, just for the period 30th November to 30th March.

```
      Dates               Col1   Col2
11178 2018-10-27 12:00:00  -1   -3
11179 2018-10-27 18:00:00  -2    2
11180 2018-10-28 00:00:00   1    8
11181 2018-10-28 06:00:00  0.1 -0.2
11182 2018-10-28 12:00:00  0.2 -0.1
11183 2018-10-28 18:00:00  0.2  0.03
11184 2018-10-29 00:00:00  0.3  0.07
11185 2018-10-29 06:00:00  0.2 -0.2
11186 2018-10-29 12:00:00  0.05 -0.4
11187 2018-10-29 18:00:00  0.02 -0.5
11188 2018-10-30 00:00:00  0.02 -0.6
11189 2018-10-30 06:00:00 -0.05 -0.7
```

I can remove certain days or months via

```
df = df.loc[~(df['Dates'].dt.month.eq(4))]
```

Which removes April as an example. I just cannot seem to find an efficient way to do the same range of dates for each year, so I can eventually do this iteratively by shifting the period back by a day each time.

The date column is currently in datetime format.

Comment: Try: `df.loc[~df['Dates'].dt.month.between(4,11)`]

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't this just delete certain months? I am trying to take two dates given by month and day and then get that period for every year.

Comment: Is it possible that you add an expected output based on your example data? This way I can visually see what you try to do, because i'm not sure if I understand your explanation.

Comment: I can attempt to, it would be a lot of data. Essentially, an example would be to say I wanted Dec 25th to Jan 5th data for every year in my dataframe. Just that period's data for each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imagine that you want to select only datas from **November 30** to **March 30**:

then 
you can divide between months that you select completely and months of which you only select a few days:

**1.you select completely: December January and February.**

```
Dcember_Jan_Feb=~df['Dates'].dt.month.between(3,11)
```

**you select on November 30, and you also select from March 1 to March 30 (March has 31 days)**

```
Nov_30=df['Dates'].dt.month.eq(11)&df['Dates'].dt.day.between(30,30)
March_1_to_30=df['Dates'].dt.month.eq(3)&df['Dates'].dt.day.between(1,30)
```

**Finally, apply your filter:**

```
df_filtered=df[Dcember_Jan_Feb|Nov_30|March_1_to_30]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a trick way of doing it

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('11178', '2018-10-27 12:00:00', '-1', '-3'), ('11179', '2018-03-30 18:00:00', '-2', '2'), ('11180', '2018-10-28 00:00:00', '1', '8'), ('11181', '2018-10-28 06:00:00', '0.1', '-0.2'), ('11182', '2018-10-28 12:00:00', '0.2', '-0.1'), ('11183', '2018-10-28 18:00:00', '0.2', '0.03'), ('11184', '2018-4-29 00:00:00', '0.3', '0.07'), ('11185', '2018-9-29 06:00:00', '0.2', '-0.2'), ('11186', '2018-10-29 12:00:00', '0.05', '-0.4'), ('11187', '2018-10-29 18:00:00', '0.02', '-0.5'), ('11188', '2018-10-30 00:00:00', '0.02', '-0.6'), ('11189', '2018-10-30 06:00:00', '-0.05', '-0.7')], columns=('ID', 'Dates', 'Col1', 'Col2'))
df = df.set_index("ID")
df.Dates = pd.to_datetime(df.Dates)

df[~(df.Dates.dt.month*100 + df.Dates.dt.day).between(330, 930, inclusive=False)]
```

**Description**

- 100*month + day will convert date as 3 digit number like 330 will be march 30 and 930 will be september 30
- you want to exclude dates between 330 and 930 so we use not operator to dates within it